# Ayuda con esta consulta de MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

desearía que me ayuden con un problema, pues estoy aprendiendo y tengo un trabajo urgente:
Tengo una tabla llamada 'vendedor', otra llamada 'factura', están relacionadas con una llave foránea. 
Además existe otra tabla llamada 'producto', relacionada con 'factura'.

[image: Consulta actual]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito mostrar los productos que ha vendido cada vendedor, valga la redundancia.

Con GROUP BY intento agrupo por vendedor, pero, no sé como hacer para que salgan todos los productos que ha vendido. Imagen de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Andrés, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. La consulta parece correcta, **según lo que has dicho sobre cómo están relacionadas tus tablas**, entonces, ¿cuál es el problema en sí?

Comment: Comparte tu diagrama @Andrés Vélez

Comment: Necesito mostrar todos los productos vendidos por cada vendedor. Por ej: vendedor1 vendió pan, leche, carne. Con la consulta que tengo actualmente me muestra: vendedor1 vendió pan, vendedor1 vendió leche, vendedor1 vendió carne.

Comment: Si como dices, relacionas los productos en la tabla facturas mediante esto: `factura.fk_id_producto = producto.id_producto` y a los vendedores con las facturas mediante esto: `vendedor.id_vendedor = factura.fk_id_vendedor`, los datos deberían mostrarse, **si es que hay datos**. El hecho es que aún no has dicho **cuál es el problema en realidad**. Ni siquiera sabemos si tus tablas tienen datos, si estas son columnas en sí: `fk_id_vendedor`, `fk_id_producto` o si son nombres de llaves primarias, etc. Por favor, sé más claro en tu pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Ya adjunté imagenes para explicarme mejor.

Comment: Tu esquema me confunde más todavía. Según la imagen tú tienes una columna llamada `ID_PRODUCTO` y otra llamada `ID_VENDEDOR` en la tabla `FACTURA`, mientras que en la consulta llamas a esas columnas  usando el prefijo `fk_`.  ¿A qué se debe eso? ¿No debería ser: `INNER JOIN factura ON (vendedor.id_vendedor = factura.id_vendedor)
INNER JOIN producto ON (factura.id_producto = producto.id_producto)`?  Si quieres los productos de un vendedor en específico sólo tienes que poner un `WHERE id_vendedor = ...`

Comment: No entiendo nada.. cual es el problema que tenes con la consulta? no necesitas ni un group by ni nada... salvo que quieras sumar algo o agrupar algo, cosa que no parece que quieras hacer. Cual es el sentido de agrupar por vendedor si queres mostrar todos los productos?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no esta bien la relación entre producto y factura la relación entre producto y factura es de muchos a muchos

Comment: Lo de 'fk' es porque así lo deseé hacer. Si es necesario agrupar por vendedor, para mostrar cuáles productos vendió, posteriormente necesito sumar el valor de ésos productos para mostrar el total de sus ventas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema planteado es un caso típico de pivote de tabla. Donde se necesita pasar de un resultado así:

```
-------------------------------
| Vendedor | Producto | Total |
-------------------------------
| Juan     | Carne    | 100   |
-------------------------------
| Pedro    | Leche    | 20    |
-------------------------------
| Pedro    | Carne    | 60    |
-------------------------------
```

a uno de esta forma:

```
------------------------------------
| Vendedor | Carne | Leche | Total |
------------------------------------
| Juan     | 100   | 0     | 100   |
------------------------------------
| Pedro    | 60    | 20    | 80    |
------------------------------------
```

Es una pregunta común, en algunos motores de bases de datos es mas fácil solucionarlo que en otros, incluso algunas veces es mas fácil resolver el tema usando un lenguaje de programación sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table, o buscar en google más acerca de como realizar consultas con pivote.